# How to assign integer value from an array to an array of string

Tags: python, excel, list, csv, variable-assignment

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_file = 'Bruv.csv'

names = []
Bar = []
Price = []

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        names.append(row.get('Sizes'))
        Bar.append(row.get('Product'))
        Price.append(row.get('Price'))

GG = pd.DataFrame()
GG['Sizes'] = names
GG['Bars'] = Bar
GG['Prices'] = Price
print(GG)

Bar=np.array(Bar).astype('str').tolist()

print("The array:", Bar)
```

This is my code with the CSV being

| Sizes | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10x8 | 8 | .25 |
| :---- | 10 | .29 |

In this code I am reading data from CSV. Upon reading the Bar array I converted that array into a string of array. I was wondering if there were any ways possible to assign that string array value to an array value from the Price array which is integer array.
Pretty much I want the code to traverse through both array and set `str(Bar[i]) = Price[j]`. Pretty much treat the Product column as an array of variables and set values to them so that ex. `'8' = .25` , `'10' = .29`
Any libraries that can be used or any method ?

Answer (score 0):

In the loop itself you can do it as ,

```
Product.append("'"+row.get('Product')+"' ="+row.get('Price')) #if u need as string

or

Product.append({ "'"+row.get('Product')+"': "+row.get('Price')+"}") #if u need as dictionary
```